# session values not passing from one controller to another in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have stored the session varible in one controller and getting the value in another controller but the value is not passing

here is one controller

```
function control1 {
$this->session->set_userdata(array(
        'value1'                =>  $this->input->post('value1'),
        'value2'                =>  $this->input->post('value2'),
);

  echo $this->session->userdata('value1'); //it returns value 

}
function control2 {

echo $this->session->userdata('value1'); //it returns empty value 
}
```

What may be the reason for this

Comment: In codeigniter for common function you need to use this in your extends class or use as helper or library isn't possible to pass district value from one controller to other controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the session has been set in the second controller like this:

```
    function control2 {
     if (!isset ($this->session->userdata('value1'))){
         redirect('control1');
     } else {
       echo $this->session->userdata('value1'); //it returns empty value 
    }
```

If you haven't run through the control1 first, there won't be any session set yet, you see.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->session->set_userdata( 'values', array(
            'value1'                =>  $this->input->post('value1'),
            'value2'                =>  $this->input->post('value2'),
    ) );
    $a = $this->session->userdata('values'); //it returns value
    print_r( $a );
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 0):

How the way you go into `control2()`? I mean, did you call `control1()` first to set the sessions value before goes to `control2()`? If so then the sessions value should be passed.